# Is there any way to change the message of empty data in RSuite-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, rsuite

I would like to change the message that appears when the prop data is an empty array. I cannot find any prop to modify this. Is there any solution for this? I would like to translate this message to other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prop `locale` that allows this behavior to get done. You can pass an object to this prop in order to change the message of empty data as follows:

```
locale={{ emptyMessage: "No data found"}}
```